# Disabled toggle button when other toggle button is clicked

Tags: javascript

I have 3 toggle buttons that are called the same function.

HTML:

```html
<button id="gen"  type="button" onchange='relasi("Gen")' > 1 </button>
<button id="imp"  type="button" onchange='relasi("Imp")' > 2 </button>
<button id="agr"  type="button" onchange='relasi("Agr")' > 4 </button>
```

I set my toggle button value like this:

```
let togButton = false;
```

Relasi() function:

```
function relasi(type) {
  if(togButton = !togButton){   //this means that the user had clicked the button so the value changed
       if(type === "Gen"){
         // set other button than Gen button disabled
       }
       if(type === "Imp"){
         // set other button than Imp button disabled
       }
       if(type === "Agr"){
        // set other button than Agr button disabled
       }
  } else {
      // this means that user hasn't clicked the button OR had clicked the same button twice
     // set ALL the buttons to enable
  }
}
```

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

A toggle button that when user hasn't clicked the button yet, the button value will be false. When user clicked the button, the value will change to true. And then, when the user clicked the button again the value will return to false (back to the original assigned value). This goes on and on.

At the same time, while one toggle button is in the state of true, I want the other toggle buttons to be disabled. This means that user only can click one button and make that button value true. To enable back other toggle buttons, user needs to click the true button again to make it false.

Hope my explanation is understandable. How can I achieve this using Vanilla Javascript?

Comment: although `if(togButton = !togButton){ ` is "legal" it doesn't make very readable code and looks sort-of "funny" next to your strict equality checking (`===`) of simple strings. 
but the thing you're looking for is `getElementById` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: Could you please post the full code of the function `relasi` so we can see what you've tried and why it isn't working?

Comment: If you have 3 different buttons, you can't use a single toggle variable. But why don't you use radio buttons for this, they implement this logic automatically.

Comment: @Barmar I think @Floppydisx's problem wouldn't be solved by radio buttons (they don't **disable** the other buttons when one is selected), but rather 3 of `<input type="checkbox">` or simply sticking with `<button>` if they're connected to something else.

Answer (score 1):

## Modelling Your Logic

A useful step in developing your application is to model the flow of your logic. A great tool for this is [stately.ai](https://stately.ai). While you can use the state machine generated by the visual model of your logic directly in your code with [XState](https://xstate.js.org/) and [React](https://react.dev), it is very easy to convert this visual model of your logic into another software design pattern that better suits your needs (i.e. is easier to write in plain JavaScript without libraries).

Below we can see an example of what the logic you need might look like. Click the image to see the example live.

[image: A state machine for selecting one of three different options and then unselecting that option.]

### Implementation of the Model

In the example implementation below, I've opted to use [the Model View Controller software design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Notes:

- Changed from `<button>` to `<input type="checkbox">` to handle the state of the toggle. You can style away the checkboxes if you wish.

  - Alternatively, you can switch back to buttons and modify the style of the buttons and figure out what Aria roles and attributes to add to the buttons to make them accessible.
- In the Controller, I've also opted to block changes to the not selected checkboxes when one is selected instead of outright disabling the checkboxes.

  - It would be more accessible to notify the user that they can't select that checkbox, why they can't, and what they can do instead.

```js
class Model {
  state = 'unselected'
  transition(type) {
    if (this.state === 'unselected') {
      switch (type) {
        case 'SELECT_GEN':
          this.state = 'selected.gen'
          break
        case 'SELECT_IMP':
          this.state = 'selected.imp'
          break
        case 'SELECT_AGR':
          this.state = 'selected.agr'
          break
      }
    } else if (this.state.startsWith('selected')) {
      if (type === 'UNSELECT') this.state = 'unselected'
    }
    view.updateCheckboxes()
  }
}
const model = new Model()

class Controller {
  checkboxIDs = ['gen', 'imp', 'agr']
  constructor() {
    for (const id of this.checkboxIDs) {
      const checkbox = document.getElementById(id)
      checkbox.addEventListener('change', _ => {
        if (model.state === 'unselected') {
          model.transition(`SELECT_${id.toUpperCase()}`)
        } else if (model.state === `selected.${id}`) {
          model.transition('UNSELECT')
        } else {
          // Prevent checking of the checkbox
          checkbox.checked = false
          event.stopImmediatePropagation()
          // TODO: Improve UX by adding a message that explains why you can't select more than one checkbox and how to change your selection.
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
const controller = new Controller()

class View {
  checkboxIDs = ['gen', 'imp', 'agr']
  updateCheckboxes() {
    for (const id of this.checkboxIDs) {
      const checkbox = document.getElementById(id)
      if (model.state === `selected.${id}`) checkbox.checked = true
      else checkbox.checked = false
    }
  }
}
const view = new View()
```

```html
<label>1 <input type="checkbox" id="gen"></label>
<label>2 <input type="checkbox" id="imp"></label>
<label>4 <input type="checkbox" id="agr"></label>
```